# How to perform a parallel reduction to an array with Python/Numba

Tags: python, parallel-processing, numba

I'm effectively looking for a way around [this issue](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/3681). I understand reducing a larger array into a smaller array (for example, if you had some sort of particle simulation and you were summing moments to an array of gridpoints) results in a race condition because the target array gets thread-locked while it's being accessed, causing other threads to drop values and resulting in erroneous output. A simple way around that would be to have each thread accumulate its values on a copy of the target array (since there may only be hundreds of gridpoints, but millions of particles), and then add those arrays up outside the parallel loop.

However, I wouldn't have a clue where to start with this. My problem basically boils down to "How can I create a local copy of an array for each thread, do some operations, and sum them up at the end?". A simplified example of this may be:

```
def deposit_particles_to_grid(ploc, pweight, grid):
    '''
    ploc    : (N)   : Particle location as an index in the grid array, leftmost point
    pweight : (Nx3) : Particle weights as a float across 3 gridpoints
    grid    : (M)   : Target array gridpoints where M << N
    '''
    for ii in nb.prange(ploc.shape[0]):
        grid[ploc[ii]]     += pweight[ii, 0]
        grid[ploc[ii] + 1] += pweight[ii, 1]
        grid[ploc[ii] + 2] += pweight[ii, 2]
    return
```

Here, ploc.shape[0] may be in the tens or hundreds of millions, whereas grid may only have hundreds or thousands of points. Ideally it would be nice to 'chunk' the ploc and pweight arrays into n_threads and give each thread its own copy of 'grid'. I'm just not sure how to do this.

EDITED the example to be more representative of my current non-parallelized code. Instead of just a one-for-one histogram, each point is distributed across 3 contiguous points as defined in pweight.

Comment: What you are doing isn't really a reduction, it is a histogram. You mind find some inspiration here: https://numba.pydata.org/numba-examples/examples/density_estimation/histogram/results.html

Comment: That does make sense! Would this be similar if each particle had some weighting over more than one gridpoint? E.g. if pweight was a 3xN array that distributed each particle over ploc, ploc+1 and ploc+2 (for a 3 point weighting)

Comment: Also additionally, is there a non-CUDA version of this for CPU parallelization? I see what they're doing by using the atomic.add() from the cuda.jit(), but it seems like there's something automatic that CUDA does here (spawning certain things into their own threads) that may not be done with a straight CPU parallelization.

Comment: I am not much help beyond that, sorry -- I literally just searched for "Numba histogram" to get you started. Once you have a design pattern or operation name to work with it makes it easier to do some research. All my Numba work is GPU based.

Comment: No worries! Thanks for the hint. I've been doing some googling and it seems to come down to the lack of support for atomic operations on CPU-based njit() functions and race conditions. It seems like a deceptively simple problem, so its difficult for me to tell if it's something obvious I'm missing, or fundamentally much more difficult than I think.

Answer (score 3):

Answering my own question because for unskilled people such as myself this may be useful. Basically all I did was create a new array with an extra axis for each thread and sum across that axis at the end. This parallelizes the deposition of the values (which is the most intensive part), and prevents a race condition because each thread has its own axis.

I make no claims about whether or not this is massively scalable or anything, but for my purposes it works just fine. I welcome any improvements on this though! I know a speedup could be had if the grid_threads memory was preallocated (in cases where this function may be called multiple times).

```
@nb.njit(parallel=True)
def deposit_particles_to_grid_parallel(ploc, pweight, grid):
    '''
    ploc    : (N)   : Particle location as an index in the grid array, leftmost point
    pweight : (Nx3) : Particle weights as a float across 3 gridpoints
    grid    : (M)   : Target array gridpoints where M << N
    '''
    grid_threads = np.zeros((grid.shape[0], n_threads), dtype=grid.dtype)
    N_per_thread = ploc.shape[0] / n_threads     
    n_start_idxs = np.arange(n_threads)*N_per_thread

    for tt in nb.prange(n_threads):
        for ii in range(n_start_idxs[tt], n_start_idxs[tt]+N_per_thread):
            grid_threads[ploc[ii],     tt] += pweight[ii, 0]
            grid_threads[ploc[ii] + 1, tt] += pweight[ii, 1]
            grid_threads[ploc[ii] + 2, tt] += pweight[ii, 2]
    grid[:] = grid_threads.sum(axis=1)
    return
```

Comment: This is a good start! However, it can be still improved: the second dimension is shared between threads causing an issue called *false-sharing*. Indeed, different threads share the same cache-line implicitly causing the cache line to bounce between threads sequentially because of the cache coherence. You can easily fix by swapping the dimensions (`tt` and `ploc[ii]`, including `axis`). Moreover, besides this, note that `ploc.shape[0]` may not be divisible by `n_threads`. In that case, the remainder needs to be considered.

Comment: Thank you! I just considered the remainder problem today, solved by making N_per_thread an array defining how many values are in that 'bin'. I use another function to calculate this and n_start_idxs (since that's now a little more complicated too).

I'm not quite sure I understand how the false-sharing works. Is it a stride/order issue, or something specific to the last axis of an array? And is it solved simply by making my grid_threads in the shape (n_threads, grid.shape[0]), thus swapping them around?

Comment: Great. False-sharing is not specifically related to the dimension. It is related to the data layout in memory and how threads access memory. The last dimension is contiguous in practice. The processor cache is split in small blocks (of tipically 64 bytes). When a thread access data in memory, the processor fetch a fill cache line. When a value is modified, the cache lines hold by all the other cores are invalidated and later reloaded from memory. Thus, when threads modify data, they should not access to close locations. Switching the dimensions enable threads to accesses different cache lines.

Comment: I see! So it is somewhat related to the C/F ordering of the arrays in that you want each thread to only be accessing its own cache, instead of a single cache being tied up with multiple threads, and you avoid that by ensuring that synchronously accessed memory addresses are far enough apart!

Thank you for your help, this has been great.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in comments, this operation is called an histogram. There are two common methods to perform this operation in parallel: using atomics to protect the histogram from race conditions and using multiple thread-local histograms and a (tree-based) reduction.

Atomics are very well optimized on Nvidia GPUs, but not often really well on CPUs (relatively to GPUs). Especially on x86 processors and more specifically when there is some contention (possibly combined with a high-latency). Moreover, atomics are only interesting when there is not a lot of conflicting access and when the histogram is big regarding the number of computed items per thread. This is why atomics are often used on mainstream Nvidia GPUs. But in your case, this is likely not the best solution.

Using multiple thread-local histograms is an efficient solution in your case as the histogram seems very small compared to the number of computed values. If the number of threads is small (eg. less than 8), then it is better to perform a trivial reduction: one thread sum up the histograms of all the other threads. When the number of threads is huge (eg. more than 32) or the target architecture have strong NUMA effects, then it is better to reduce the histogram using a parallel tree-based reduction: threads are hierarchically  packed by groups and one thread per group (eg. 4 or 8 threads) perform the reduction of the histograms of all the other threads belonging to its group (this process is applied recursively until there is one final histogram).

Comment: I see, thanks! That makes sense in terms of approach and algorithm. In my case I am after the "trivial reduction" case, with each thread having its own histogram and then combining them afterwards. My question was primarily how to actually do this in numba/Python in terms of script and coding.